# CMS major gc occurs frequently

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am using CMS GC, the major gc is occurring every 2 minutes or less

I have tried to increase the value of CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime from 5 to 10 and then to 20 but it doesn't help.

Can anyone help?

Here is the configuration I am using

```
-heap-size=30g 
-XX:PermSize=512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xss256k 
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
-XX:ParGCCardsPerStrideChunk=32768 
-XX:NewSize=2g 
-XX:MaxNewSize=2g 
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=45 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=20000
```

Here is the log for the GC

```
2016-10-11T08:49:01.983-0500: 407.440: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 13557029K(29360128K)] 13766753K(31247616K), 0.4483970 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.31, real=0.45 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:02.431-0500: 407.889: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2016-10-11T08:49:07.764-0500: 413.222: [GC2016-10-11T08:49:07.765-0500: 413.222: [ParNew: 1887488K->209664K(1887488K), 4.2307640 secs] 15444517K->14525267K(31247616K), 4.2309270 secs] [Times: user=4.32 sys=3.49, real=4.23 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:22.023-0500: 427.480: [GC2016-10-11T08:49:22.023-0500: 427.480: [ParNew: 1887488K->209664K(1887488K), 1.9675120 secs] 16203091K->14978753K(31247616K), 1.9676860 secs] [Times: user=3.20 sys=1.50, real=1.96 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:28.899-0500: 434.356: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 20.218/26.467 secs] [Times: user=58.98 sys=12.86, real=26.46 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:28.899-0500: 434.356: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2016-10-11T08:49:28.997-0500: 434.454: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.096/0.098 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.01, real=0.10 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:28.997-0500: 434.454: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2016-10-11T08:49:34.215-0500: 439.672: [GC2016-10-11T08:49:34.215-0500: 439.672: [ParNew: 1887488K->209664K(1887488K), 1.9914300 secs] 16656577K->15383793K(31247616K), 1.9915960 secs] [Times: user=3.22 sys=1.24, real=1.99 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:40.097-0500: 445.554: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 9.002/11.100 secs] [Times: user=29.07 sys=3.17, real=11.10 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:40.098-0500: 445.555: [GC[YG occupancy: 1113559 K (1887488 K)]2016-10-11T08:49:40.098-0500: 445.555: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.6648450 secs]2016-10-11T08:49:40.763-0500: 446.220: [weak refs processing, 0.0005380 secs]2016-10-11T08:49:40.764-0500: 446.221: [class unloading, 0.0115730 secs]2016-10-11T08:49:40.775-0500: 446.233: [scrub symbol table, 0.0120750 secs]2016-10-11T08:49:40.788-0500: 446.245: [scrub string table, 0.0011940 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 15174129K(29360128K)] 16287688K(31247616K), 0.6943980 secs] [Times: user=2.65 sys=0.00, real=0.69 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:40.793-0500: 446.250: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2016-10-11T08:49:43.096-0500: 448.553: [GC2016-10-11T08:49:43.096-0500: 448.553: [ParNew: 1887318K->209664K(1887488K), 0.4514140 secs] 16282520K->14815052K(31247616K), 0.4515870 secs] [Times: user=1.67 sys=0.00, real=0.45 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:46.798-0500: 452.255: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 5.552/6.005 secs] [Times: user=19.43 sys=1.14, real=6.00 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:46.798-0500: 452.255: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2016-10-11T08:49:47.236-0500: 452.693: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.438/0.438 secs] [Times: user=0.79 sys=0.50, real=0.44 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:49.244-0500: 454.701: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 13969830K(29360128K)] 15630493K(31247616K), 2.1488470 secs] [Times: user=2.15 sys=0.00, real=2.15 secs]
2016-10-11T08:49:51.394-0500: 456.851: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
```

Comment: "I didn't see any minor gc"? I see several minor gc's: at 413.222, at 427.480, at 439.672 and at 448.553

Comment: @ThomasKläger You are right. I update the post

Answer (score 0):

As per the option **CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction** your marking phase will start at 45% of heap which in your case will be **14495514K**.

As per your GC log:

> 2016-10-11T08:49:07.764-0500: 413.222: [GC2016-10-11T08:49:07.765-0500: 413.222: [ParNew: 1887488K->209664K(1887488K), 4.2307640 secs] 15444517K->**14525267K**(31247616K), 4.2309270 secs] [Times: user=4.32 sys=3.49, real=4.23 secs]

your live data set after a Full GC is 14525267K, which is above the said threshold therefore you face almost constant GC.

You should increase CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction, so it can accomodate your live data set. It should be a bit above your live data set + young gen heap size, which in your case would be about 16,5G - I'd say setting **CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction**=55 should improve your situation.

Comment: which also highlights that one should try to understand the options one is using. cargo-culting is bad, m'kay?

Comment: @bashnesnos The value you specify is the total memory used in both young and old generation. It is not the total of live data. As there could be unused data in the old generation which could be collected by major gc

Comment: @Robinson though the behavior is still explained correctly. Update your post with Full GC information, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @the8472 it's carved in stone in many places, but people tend to carve it on their foreheads also.